# Linux/Bash: Create relative soft links to files in directory tree?

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, links

I'd like to make links to all files in a directory tree.
Which means, create the same directory structure and make the links in them to the respective subdirectory in the original dir.

That could be done with

```
cp -R -s ../foo .
```

But - that needs an absolute path. So rather

```
cp -R -s `readlink -e ../foo` `readlink -e .`
```

I would like the resulting links to be relative.

Is there some easy way? E.g. some script or program specialized for that.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but  user Timo Lehto helpfully pointed out that my original answer was completely wrong. I have now rewritten it and provide a working solution. My apologies, I should have tested the original better.

Answer (score 0):

This script should do what you want. It is a bit more complex than you might expect because it needs to be able to deal with arbitrary file and directory names. Including names with newlines, whitespace and globbing characters. This should work on any name you give it.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sourceDir="$1"
targetDir="."

## The name of the source directory without its path
## First, we need to strip the trailing `/` if present.
sourceDir="${sourceDir%/}"
sourceName="${sourceDir##*/}"

## Find all files and directories in $source. -print0
## is needed to deal with names with newlines
find "$sourceDir" -mindepth 1 -print0 |
        ## Read eacch file/dir found into $f. IFS= ensures
        ## we can deal with whitespace correctly and -d ''
        ## lets 'read' read null-separated values. The -r
        ## ensures that backspaces don't have special meaning. All
        ## this to be certain that this will work on arbitrary file names. 
        while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
                ##
                name="${f##$sourceDir}"
                ## Build the relative path for the symlink
                relname=$(perl -le '$ARGV[0]=~s|/[^/]+|/..|g; 
                            $ARGV[0]=~s|../..$|$ARGV[1]/$ARGV[2]|; 
                            print $ARGV[0]' "$f" "$sourceName" "$name")
                ## If this is a directory, create it
                if [ -d "$f" ]; then
                        mkdir -p "$targetDir/$name"
                ## If a file, link to it. 
                else
                        ln -s "$relname" "$targetDir/$name"
                fi
        done
```

Save the script and make it executable and then `cd` into your target directory and run the script with the source directory as an argument. For example, to duplicate the directory `../target` in the current directory, you would run:

```
foo.sh  ../target/
```

Comment: Ironic how you call this straightforward, but unfortunately your script does not work. :) The first bit works almost, it's just missing `./` before `${...` and then it succeeds at copying the directory structure. Btw. an alternative and much more readable solution for that part would be to use `rsync -a --include='*/' --exclude='*' ../foo/ .`, but YMMV. However, the second part does not work at all. It creates all the links on the root level on the duplicate cloned tree. This is not what the OP wanted. I couldn't come up with a sane working solution, but perhaps, given this feedback, you can.

Comment: @TimoLehto oh wow, you're quite right. The first part did work, I'm not sure what problem you saw there, the `./` is implied when not given. However, the rest most certainly didn't work. Thanks for pointing it out. I've completely rewritten my answer and now provide an actual working solution.